# Eloquent: Using Model::where + with not displaying data

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to create a query using Products Model (refers to Product Table) with Photo Model / Table, Features and locations.

My idea is to filter results of table products in order to display only the information of the current logged user.

This is the query:

```
        $product = Product::where('companyId', '=', Auth::user()->companyId)
->with(['photos','features','locs']);
```

For some reason I cannot find why when I include

```
Product::where('companyId', '=', Auth::user()->companyId)
```

the query stop working.

its possible to use Products:where(condition) + wish?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you see?? Check in your error log

Comment: Post structures or table names of the 3 models which you want to use with. And your relationships also

Comment: thank you @LeenaPatel I was missing use Auth; and I saw it on log.

Comment: great that you solved it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this one ...

```
Product::where('companyId', Auth::user()->companyId)->get();
```

Comment: in that case could work, my problem is when I include ->with

Comment: thanks it was a problem with a Auth missing. my mistake.